# Issue with changing URL and Home in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

Had an issue with the URL and Home fields in Wordpress being grayed out. To fix this, I deleted the following lines of code from the wp-config.php file:

define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');

define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');

This worked and allowed me to edit the URL and Home fields. I changed it from the IP address to the domain name that we are using. After saving, I can't access the website anymore. When typing in the domain name we are using I get a connection timed out error. If I type in the public IP address I get the Apache2 Ubuntu default page. If I type in the IP address followed by /admin (generally points to the WP login page) I get a Not Found error.

I can still SSH in via the Amazon Web Services portal, so I don't think all is lost, but I'm unsure as to what is causing this. I can also access 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin, but I'm not sure if that helps at all. I'm very new to this web dev thing.

Comment: Are you sure the domain is pointing to the server? Check its DNS records.

Comment: please could you send the domain, check the propagation here whatsmydns.net, also enable the Debug in wordpress https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/debugging-wordpress-how-to-use-wp_debug/

Comment: Domain is jrk17.com

Just checked on whatsmydns.net and jrk17.com is pointing towards my public IP

Comment: Nevermind, I was mistaken. jrk17.com is pointing towards our old IP address. My coworker rebooted our site on AWS which gave us a new IP address. I will have the domain pointed at the new IP address and update.

Comment: I have also enabled debugging now